# I am not able to insert textarea value and image upload in database using ajax serialize ()

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am not able to insert textarea value in database using  ajax serialize ().

```
<form id="addform" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="link" class="control-label col-xs-3">Journal Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Journal Name"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="link" class="control-label col-xs-3">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea name="description" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80" value=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="link" class="control-label col-xs-3">Image</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" > 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('#save11').click(function(){          
    $.ajax({                
        type: "POST",
        url: "page/add-journal.php",
        data: $('#addform').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href="home-page.php";       
        }
    });
});
```

```php
<?php
    include '../dbConnection.php';

    echo $sql="insert into journal set name='".$_POST['name']."', description='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."', price1='".$_POST['price1']."', price2='".$_POST['price2']."', price3='".$_POST['price3']."', file='".$file."', active='".$_POST['active']."'"; 
    $query = mysql_query($sql);             
?>
```

Comment: You have to pass your variable in mysql_escape_string function, lot of time when user use any special chars in their input the mysql query getting errors.

Comment: You have to decode the POST data using json_decode.  

Then you should run the values through mysqli_real_escape_string to escape any special characters. You shouldn't be using mysql_query, but mysqli_query (mysql functions are deprecated as of 5.5).

Comment: @GeoffAtkins..Actually all data is inserting easily except textarea value.I used texteditor in textarea,that y textarea value is not insert in database

Comment: @meena what's the datatype of your column in your table in which you are going to store the textarea value ?

Comment: @NipunTyagi...data type is mediumtext.

Comment: @meena Can you post here your content that you get in your variable for textarea ?

Comment: description='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'])."'                            description is the name of textarea